# Adding layer control to Mapbox.js map with data that is featureLayers, that shows only the first layer on load?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, feature-layer, layer-control

I have been tasked with finishing off an abandoned project in an area I have no expertise in.

I have successfully loaded my 3 geoJSON files into a map, symbolized them and given them popups.

What I can't figure out is how to get my layer control to work for those layers. The basemap toggling works fine, but I am lost on how to make my vector layers toggle, and have a specific one turned on when the map loads.

The material in the map is sensitive (not actually strawberries) so I can't give a demo.

```
<div id='map' class='map'> </div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'REMOVED';
// define map as an object, set centre and zoom level, add basemap layer from mapbox
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([63.168759, -96.680897],5)

// **AJAX request, subject to the Same Origin Policy for loading all geoJSON files **keep them where they are or it will break:
// define Strawberries as a layer, load it, check, when fully loaded, symbolize from simplestyle-spec, bind a pop-up to the object that displays properties, add to map.
var strawberries = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  strawberries.loadURL('strawberries.geojson');
strawberries.on('ready', function(layer){
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': '#7a77a9',
          'marker-size': 'medium',
          'marker-symbol':'college'
      }));
      marker.bindPopup('<h6>' + marker.feature.properties.strawberry_name + '</h6>', { closeButton: true });
    });
    map.fitBounds(strawberries.getBounds());
  });
strawberries.addTo(map);

// define strawberries2 as a layer, load it, check, when fully loaded, symbolize from simplestyle-spec, bind a pop-up to the object that displays properties, add to map.
var strawberries2 = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  strawberries2.loadURL('strawberries2.geojson');
strawberries2.on('ready', function(layer){
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': '#a21a4a',
          'marker-size': 'small',
          'marker-symbol':'hospital'
      }));
      marker.bindPopup('<h6>' + marker.feature.properties.strawberries2_name + '</h6>', { closeButton: true });
    });
  });
strawberries2.addTo(map);

// define strawberries3 as a layer, load it, check, when fully loaded, symbolize from simplestyle-spec, bind a pop-up to the object that displays properties add to map.
var strawberries3 = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  strawberries3.loadURL('strawberries3.geojson');
strawberries3.on('ready', function(layer){
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': '#208064',
          'marker-size': 'small',
          'marker-symbol':'building'
      }));
      marker.bindPopup('<h6>' + marker.feature.properties.strawberry_name + '</h6>', { closeButton: true });
    });
  });
strawberries3.addTo(map);

L.control.layers( {
    'Topo Map': L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10').addTo(map),
    'Imagery': L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9')
}, {
    'Strawberries': L.mapbox.featureLayer('strawberries'),
    'Strawberry 2': L.mapbox.featureLayer('strawberries2'),
    'Strawberry 3': L.mapbox.featureLayer('strawberries3')
}).addTo(map);  

</script>
```

Can you help with my code or by pointing me to an example that covers layer control in mapbox.js using multiple geoJSON files coming from a URL?

---

**Update:

```
L.control.layers( {
    'Topo Map': L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10').addTo(map),
    'Imagery': L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9')
}, {
    'Strawberries': strawberries,
    'Strawberry 2': strawberries2,
    'Strawberry 3': strawberries3
}, {
      collapsed: false
    }).addTo(map);
```

gets me so close, but how can I only have the 'strawberries' layer selected in the checkbox on load?

---

Update 2

```
L.control.layers( null, {
    '<img src="image.png" /> Strawberry': (strawberries).addTo(map),
    '<img src="image2.png" /> Strawberry 2': strawberries2,
    '<img src="image3.png" /> Strawberry 3': strawberries3
}, {
      collapsed: false
    }).addTo(map);
```

Doesn't work either (but also doesn't break it). How can I only have the 'strawberries' layer selected in the legend control checkboxes on load, not all 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was adding each to the map too early overriding the layer control object. Functional code looks like:

```
<div id='map' class='map'> </div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'REMOVED';
// define map as an object, set centre and zoom level, add basemap layer from mapbox
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([63.168759, -96.680897],5)

// **AJAX request, subject to the Same Origin Policy for loading all geoJSON files **keep them where they are or it will break:
// define Strawberries as a layer, load it, check, when fully loaded, symbolize from simplestyle-spec, bind a pop-up to the object that displays properties, add to map.
var strawberries = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  strawberries.loadURL('strawberries.geojson');
strawberries.on('ready', function(layer){
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': '#7a77a9',
          'marker-size': 'medium',
          'marker-symbol':'college'
      }));
      marker.bindPopup('<h6>' + marker.feature.properties.strawberry_name + '</h6>', { closeButton: true });
    });
    map.fitBounds(strawberries.getBounds());
  });
strawberries.addTo(map);

// define strawberries2 as a layer, load it, check, when fully loaded, symbolize from simplestyle-spec, bind a pop-up to the object that displays properties, add to map.
var strawberries2 = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  strawberries2.loadURL('strawberries2.geojson');
strawberries2.on('ready', function(layer){
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': '#a21a4a',
          'marker-size': 'small',
          'marker-symbol':'hospital'
      }));
      marker.bindPopup('<h6>' + marker.feature.properties.strawberries2_name + '</h6>', { closeButton: true });
    });
  });


// define strawberries3 as a layer, load it, check, when fully loaded, symbolize from simplestyle-spec, bind a pop-up to the object that displays properties add to map.
var strawberries3 = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  strawberries3.loadURL('strawberries3.geojson');
strawberries3.on('ready', function(layer){
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          'marker-color': '#208064',
          'marker-size': 'small',
          'marker-symbol':'building'
      }));
      marker.bindPopup('<h6>' + marker.feature.properties.strawberry_name + '</h6>', { closeButton: true });
    });
  });


L.control.layers( {
    'Topo Map': L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10').addTo(map),
    'Imagery': L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9')
}, {
    'Strawberries': L.mapbox.featureLayer('strawberries'),
    'Strawberry 2': L.mapbox.featureLayer('strawberries2'),
    'Strawberry 3': L.mapbox.featureLayer('strawberries3')
}).addTo(map);  

</script>
```